# What is "bacto" peptone?

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, terminology, protocol, growth-media

Standard recipes for yeast medium often include "bacto-peptone". Is this the same as bacteriological peptone? Is there an authoritative source that spells it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See here](http://www.bd.com/ds/productCenter/211820.asp). *Bacto* is a brand which used to be marketed by Difco. It is a casein (milk protein) hydrolysate.

Comment: @leonardo that's a pity since it included a lot of useful information.